# NuGet Package Manager installing System dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, add-references-dialog

I have installed a 3rd Party .Net library https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet using NuGet Package manager like so:

```
Install-Package SocketIoClientDotNet
```

I have noticed that this has imported several custom dlls as well as many .NET dlls such as:

```
  System.Collections.Immutable
  System.Collections.Specialized
  System.Linq
  System.Net.NameResolution
  System.Net.Security
  System.Net.Sockets
  System.Runtime.Extensions
  System.Runtime.InteropServices
  System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms
  System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding
  System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives
  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
  System.Text.RegularExpressions
  System.Threading
  System.Threading.Timer
```

I see that these dlls all have been imported into a folder called 'packages' in my solutions directory.

I do not want to have to include all these files in my **installer** so I was thinking that because these are system .NET dlls, can I not simply add them manually myself (Right Click-->Add Reference) and forget about them being pulled in via the package manager?

BUT when I try to add them using Visual Studios 'Add Reference' I **do not see** many of them in Assemblies-Framework or Assemblies-Extensions.

Comment: Having the same problem. I guess it's because ms trying to do cross-platform but I'm not doing dotnet core at all. So wondering why it happened.